# Assigning values to a numpy array to zeros array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, assign

I've been trying to assign values from an array to another array, specifically from an array with values to a zeros array. Position of these values in the zeros array is also very essential. This is also a small piece of a bigger code, the bigger picture is to be able to import values from an excel spreadsheet into a zeros matrix. This is my problem:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.zeros((2,3))
P= np.asarray ([1,2,3,4,5,6])
for i in range(0,2):
for j in range(0,3):
    x[i,j] = P[(i-1)*3+j] # 3 is the counter in x direction, nx
x
```

With this code, the output is (which is what I want):

```
array([[4., 5., 6.],
       [1., 2., 3.]])
```

However if I try to the expand the array, as such:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.zeros((3,3))
P= np.asarray ([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])
for i in range(0,3):
for j in range(0,3):
    x[i,j] = P[(i-1)*3+j] # 3 is the counter in x direction, nx
x
```

The output is:

```
array([[7., 8., 9.],
       [1., 2., 3.],
       [4., 5., 6.]])
```

*I expect the output to be:*

```
array([[7., 8., 9.],
       [4., 5., 6.],
       [1., 2., 3.]])
```

Is there a reason why the ouput is changing with the expansion of the array?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to iterate:

```
In [323]: P=np.arange(1,10).reshape(3,3)[::-1,:]                                                       
In [324]: P                                                                                            
Out[324]: 
array([[7, 8, 9],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [1, 2, 3]])
```

As for your loop, look a the i,j's:

```
In [325]: for i in range(3): 
     ...:     for j in range(3): 
     ...:         print(i,j,(i-1)*3+j) 
     ...:                                                                                              
0 0 -3
0 1 -2
0 2 -1
1 0 0
1 1 1
1 2 2
2 0 3
2 1 4
2 2 5
```

Comment: This is a small piece of a bigger code. The main essence of the code is to assign values from an excel sheet to a zeros matrix which may take the form of several different dimensions.

Comment: In any case, your calculation produces negative values for some cases.  In Python that indexes from the end.  So if you must iterate make sure the indices are right.  If `P` was 2d, you wouldn't have to do the `(i-1)*3+j` calculation; you could index with `i` and `j`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use loop, just use flip() with reshape().

```
import numpy as np

m = 3 # number of rows you want

n = 3 # number of column you want

P = np.asarray ([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])

P = np.flip(P.reshape(m,n), axis=0)

print(P)
```

```
[[7 8 9]
 [4 5 6]
 [1 2 3]]
```

If you want to assign it to a zero matrix, you can just iterate through the indices.

For example, let's say you have a much bigger zero matrix, you want to fill row x, y, z with the current matrix generated.

```
zero = np.zeros((10, 3))

print(zero.shape)

zero[[2, 5, 7], : ] = P # randomly assigning P to index 2, 5, 7th row of zero matrix

print(zero)
```

```
(10, 3)
[[0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0.]
 [7. 8. 9.]
 [0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0.]
 [4. 5. 6.]
 [0. 0. 0.]
 [1. 2. 3.]
 [0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0.]]
```

You can also loop through:

```
for i in range(3):
    zero[i,:] = P[i,:]
```

Comment: This is a small piece of a bigger code. The main essence of the code is to assign values to a zeros matrix which may take the form of several different dimensions.

Comment: updated, you can assign the generated matrix to a zero matrix.

Comment: This could work, although can there be like a counter to go row by row, instead of manually assigning the rows. Thanks

Comment: Yes, instead of [2, 5, 7], you can do something like 
```
for i in range(3):
    zero[i,:] = P[i,:]
```
Usually, loops are slower hence I didn't show.

Comment: This was really helpful, Thank you !

Comment: Welcome, don't hesitate to upvote/accept an answer if it helps :)